# Error in passing function to function template

Tags: c++, c++11

I have function templates :

```
template<typename T>
inline T fun3(T &x1, T &x2) 
    {
        return std::pow(x1,2.0) + std::pow(x2,2.0);
    }

template<typename T, typename U>
inline T fun5(U &a)
    {
        return (T(4.0+a*(-2.0),5.0+ a*3.0));
    }

template<typename F, typename T>
void min(F fun1, T& v)
{
    double x={10.0};
    v=fun1(x);
}

int main()
{
    double val;
    min(fun3(fun5),val);
    std::cout<<"value = "<<val<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I want to evaluate `fun3(fun5(x))` and have functions as shown above. But getting error as `no matching function for call to ‘Function5<double>::fun5(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’  obj1(o5.fun5(o3.fun3),-2.0,0.0,location,value);`

Can someone explain how can I pass function to `min()`?

What will change if all these functions were class templates like:

```
template<typename T>
class Fun3 {
    inline T fun3(T &x1, T &x2) 
        {
            return std::pow(x1,2.0) + std::pow(x2,2.0);
        }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class Fun5 {
    inline T fun5(U &a)
        {
            return (T(4.0+a*(-2.0),5.0+ a*3.0));
        }
};

template<typename F, typename T>
class Min {
    void min(F fun1, T& v)
    {
        double x={10.0};
        v=fun1(x);
    }
};

int main()
{
    double val;
    Fun5<double> o5;
    Fun3<decltype (o5.fun5)> o3;
    Min<???,decltype (o5.fun5)> obj; //What is here?
    obj(o3.fun3(o5.fun5),val);
    std::cout<<"value = "<<val<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what will go to commented line. 
How can I use a function object (functor) here?

Comment: When you do `min(fun3(fun5),val)` you *call* the function `fun3` and passes its returned value to the `min` function. And that won't work because `fun3` doesn't take a single argument, and none of the arguments are functions. Perhaps you should do some research about [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)?

Comment: How can I use a function object?

Comment: "I want to evaluate `fun3(fun5(x))` and have functions as shown above." But `fun3` as shown above takes two arguments and you want to pass it only one?

Comment: Totally unrelated: `std::pow` is designed to handle really nasty stuff like e to the power of pi and as a result can be a very expensive way to do simple operations like squaring a number.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to evaluate fun3(fun5(x))

```cpp
min([](auto x){ return fun3(fun5(x)); }, val);
```

There's no function composition in C++ standard library (though it can be defined with some effort.)

Comment: I didn't understand  "There's no function composition in C++ standard library" when you passed the same in first lambda parameter to `min()`

Comment: What you were trying to achieve by `fun3(fun5)`. It's not in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want fun, at least try lambdas. They are simple.
I'd say stay away from templates in the way you want to use them. I am assuming you want a simple happy life to focus on productive thing and I may be wrong. Pardon.

Still, I worked on your code a bit and would say that don't confuse template and macros. It looks like the case at least to me.
Note that the template actually instantiate the code and for that all you can pass is arguments to whatever types and specify those types while template instantiating.

Here is a [code sample at ideone](http://www.ideone.com/efmECS) - not exactly same but to show how something can be done.

`For    min(fun3(fun5),val);`

If you really want fun3 behavior, pass it. Dont expect the result to be passed just like it works for macro.

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

typedef double (*_typeofFun1)(double&);
typedef double (*_typeofFun3)(double&, double&);

template<typename T>
T fun3(T &x1, T &x2) 
    {
        return std::pow(x1,2.0) + std::pow(x2,2.0);
    }

template<typename T, typename U>
U fun5(T t, U &a)
    {
        //return (T(4.0+a*(-2.0),5.0+ a*3.0));
        return t(a,a);
    }

template <typename T>
T fun1Param(T& arg)
{
    return 2*arg;
}

template<typename F, typename T>
void min(F fun1, T& v)
{
    double x={10.0};
    v=fun1(x);
}


int main()
{
    double val = 1.0;
    double d = fun5<_typeofFun3, double> (fun3, val);
    fun3<double>(d, val);
    min<_typeofFun1>(fun1Param,val);
    std::cout<<"value = "<<val<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```